# Need to check a value from database to open a form accordingly

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I'm a bit amateur and a beginner in database and queries. What I want to do is I have a table with username and password and a usertype column. 
After username and password is checked I want to check the value in usertype and see if it is 1 the program will open up the form with admin privileges if the usertype is 2 then the I want to open up the form without admin privileges. 
I can't figure out how I will pass a query which will compare the usertype value

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cs = "provider = microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0; Data Source=C:\\Users\\Obm\\Desktop\\Emp.accdb; ";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(cs);
    conn.Open();
    string q1 = "select username,password from MyUser where username = '" + textBox1.Text + "'and password = '" + textBox2.Text + "'";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q1, conn);
    OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.Read() )
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Success");
      //After this I want to check the value in usertype column.
    }
    else
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Try Again");
    }
}
```

Comment: use `reader.Item("username")` and `reader.Item("password")`
If it works i'll post as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the `usertype` column in your query, then you can read the value from the reader. Provided that `usertype` is a string:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cs = "provider = microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0; Data Source=C:\\Users\\Obm\\Desktop\\Emp.accdb; ";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(cs);
    conn.Open();
    string q1 = "select username,password,usertype from MyUser where username = '" + textBox1.Text + "'and password = '" + textBox2.Text + "'";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q1, conn);
    OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while(reader.Read() )
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Success");
         string usertype = reader.GetString(2);
         //do something with usertype, eg if(usertype == "admin")...

     }
     reader.Close();
     conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: So I can't get a value of an int or any other type? and what is the use of ' '2' in reader.GetString(2); '

Comment: Yes, the reader class has a number of methods for reading different types I just used string as an example. 2 is the array index

Answer (score 0):

You are not fetching **usertype** from database. i.e.

```
string q1 = "select username,password from MyUser where username = '" + textBox1.Text + "'and password = '" + textBox2.Text + "'";
```

your query needs to look like like if usertype is column which is available in MyUser Table as foreign key of table Usertypes in database,

```
string q1 = "Select username, password, usertype from MyUser where username = '" + textBox1.Text + "'and password = '" + textBox2.Text + "'";
```

once you have retrieved usertype from query and executed in reader, you can make decisions based on available data.i.e. open admin form or end user form etc.